# flutter build error: Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am using flutter version 2.2.2 and the latest android studio for the moment.
I have a Flutter project that worked fine few months ago, but now - after upgrading flutter and dart - it does not run.

I tried downgrading flutter and dart, but kept getting the same error when running:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have this pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  email_validator: '^1.0.5'
  path_provider: ^1.6.18
  social_share: ^2.0.5
  firebase_admob: ^0.10.2
```

I tried changing `firebase_admob` to `google_mobile_ads` but that did not solve the problem either.

I am already using AndroidX.

Can any body see a problem? Does anybody have a possible solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT version.
I changed it to version 11.0.11 and it worked just fine.
To do that, download the right JDK and change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

IMPORTANT: a Java version too new might not work as well. Version 11 should be fine (and 8 as others over the internet stated).

Comment: So, I should register `JAVA_HOME` variable inside ~/.zshrc file right? And also run `source ~/.zshrc` to reflect the changes, right? Btw, I'm using Zsh.

Comment: It does not matter how you change the env variable, but the way you mentioned is supposed to work just fine.